# Running scripts in Spyder using windows Command Prompt or PowerShell

Tags: python, spyder

I would like to know if there is a way to run python scripts in spyder-ide using windows cmd or PowerShell instead of IPython console.

Ipython sometimes works differently than if the script is run in cmd specially for plotting packages like matplotlib, etc.

I am using Spyder latest version.

Regards

Comment: to clarify: you want to use your windows cmd to run a script in spyder? why not launch from cmd directly?

Comment: hi @Cut7er Thanks for the advice, I am wondering if there is a simple click method in spyder itself to make the code runs in cmd instead of IPython console.

Comment: i would advise opening cmd in the folder where your script lies, there you can then run it with the command `python script_name.py` ...this way your console won't close after the script execution is finished

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spyder, you can click Run > Configuration per file, which will give you plenty of options in where your Spyder-IDE-Script is launched.

[image]

Comment: Thank, it works but cmd disappears right after executing the code!. For example if the code is `print('hi')`, Spyder runs the code in cmd if the option of console is an external system terminal is selected but I cant see the result unless adding a line `input('wait')`.

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti, for that, please activate the option called *Interact with the Python console after execution*, also present in "Run > Configuration per file".

Comment: @CarlosCordoba , Thanks, it works perfect, amazing ide for python. regards

Comment: Any way to use `PowerShell` instead of `cmd` in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

I think the option you are looking for is "Execute in External System Terminal" in the options found under the menu item of [Tools] / [Preferences] / [Run]